# Use .dll developed in C# in VBA with Declare statements

Tags: vba, ms-word, com-interop

I have a class library that has a class **Calculator** with the method **Add** to add the two numbers written in c#. I want to access the method in VBA macro from Word. I can access the method easily when I make assembly COM-visible and add the COM reference in VBA in the office.

But I have to load the .dll differently using Declare statement. I have tried the following way but I am unable to load the DLL and receive the error:

[image]

**C# Class**

```
namespace Calculator
{        
    public class BasicCalculator
    {    
        public int Add(int number1, int number2)
        {
            var result = number1 + number2;               
            return result;
        }    
    }
}
```

**Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)**

```
 Option Explicit
    #IF VBA7 ThEN
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function Add Lib "C:\Calculator\Calcular.dll" (number1 As Integer, number2 As Integer) As Integer    
    #ELSE
        Public Declare Function Add Lib "C:\Calculator\Calcular.dll" (number1 As Integer, number2 As Integer) As Integer    
    #END IF

Sub Calculate()
    Dim n1 As Integer
    Dim n2 As Integer
    
    n1 = 20
    n2 = 10
    
    Dim result As Integer
    
    result = Add(n1, n2)
    
    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

Is there a way to fix the issue?

I saw a similar solution where the DLL has been loaded using Declare statement (maybe c++ dll).

Answer (score 0):

> I saw a similar solution where the DLL has been loaded using Declare statement (maybe c++ dll).

Yes, in case of unmanaged assemblies it could be possible. But you have developed a .net based application which requires loading the .net runtime. That's why you need to expose it to the COM world by making the .net assembly COM-visible and adding the COM reference in VBA in the office.